# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp() in /home/customer/www/monkinsider.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16 Stack trace:

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, themes

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp() in /home/customer/www/monkinsider.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/monkinsider.com/public_html/index.php(17): require() #1 {main} thrown in /home/customer/www/monkinsider.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 16

I don't know but since last week I am getting this error. My site is hosted on siteground and there are no updates from my side. Also, when I contacted them they said its Wordpress issue and they cant help. I tried to restore backup but only it works for 5 minutes after that error shows up again. Also, I referred to previous articles and everything seems fine the file wp-config and all. Also,I cannot even open my admin Wordpress panel.

Answer (score 2):

That's a malware.

You should scan your server and restore wp-blog-header.php with a default one.

You can download a fresh version here: https://wordpress.org/download/releases/

You won't be able to restore the account until the malware is deleted

Comment: How to know whether is it malware? Cause when I downloaded whole website folder via FTP and scanned it didn't show any error. Also, it started working from yesterday.

Comment: I fix such errors every day, and I have not ever seen any other reasons for this exact Call to undefined function wp() in wp-blog-header.php file.

Comment: what's excat resolution can you please elaborate?

Comment: I can see wp-blog-header file as it is. Content is not deleted

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case wp-load.php was empty for some reasons, not sure what caused it. I copied the files content from a different website and it fixed the issue.